# How do I implement this bubble sort differently?

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I'm looking to implement a bubble sort. I have the following code that I wrote, which uses a `for` loop inside of a `do` loop. How can I make this into a bubble sort that uses two `for` loops?

Here's my code:

```
do {
    switched = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[i-1]) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i-1];
            a[i-1] = temp;
            switched = true;
        }
    }
} while (switched);
```

(This is tagged homework, but this is studying for the final exam, not actual homework.)

Comment: "I'm looking to implement a bubble sort" - there's your problem!  (Seriously, why do they continue to insist on teaching the use of Bubblesort....)

Comment: @MitchWheat, implementing bubblesort is just starters for teaching sorting...and it helps you appreciate other sorting techniques.

Comment: Shouldn't you be starting at zero?

Comment: @MitchWheat - Nope, look at my switch. I know that it works, I've tested it.

Comment: @Don starting at 0 would look at element -1, which makes the JVM very mad at you.

Comment: Ah yes.  I didn't look carefully at the code and it's been a while since I implemented bubble sort.  ;-)

Comment: @glowcoder: I don't think the JVM complains much about C++ code.

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh this is a c++ question. Being syntactically identical (in this case) to Java it was indistinguishable. You're right, C++ code here won't get mad at you. It will just walk away telling you something went wrong and leaving you on your own.

Comment: @DeadMG Yes, yes, as I said it appeared to be a Java question at first glance. :-) I got up super early this morning to work with international clients :-( I'm gonna blame it on that! Wow. Why the hate? :(

Comment: @Mitch, it's easy to implement, it's easy to recognize bugs when you make a mistake, it's easy to illustrate how it works on paper, on a chalkboard, or even with physical objects, and it's easy to work through an example by hand. For all those reasons, it's a great a sorting algorithm to teach to beginners.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, Jonathan M: It is also easy for it to find its way into production code with disasterous consequences. I have personally seen this twice in a 26 year career.

Comment: If people in introductory programming classes are in a position to be writing production code, @Mitch, that's not the fault of the instructors who taught bubble sort. It's the fault of the managers who allowed entry-level employees to put unreviewed code into production. Twice in 26 years doesn't seem very prevalent, anyway.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: If when it was taught it had the proviso "NEVER USE THIS IN PRODUCTION CODE" hammered in at every oppurtunity then I wouldn't raise this. As to the frequency, I'm talking about my own personal limited experience; as to prevalency that depends on the cost of the damage done. Also note: I'm not the only person that feels this way about Bubblesort's teaching!

Comment: Moshe: your comment is directed at me and you meant @Don Ruby

Comment: @glowcoder: Because your participation so far is "Oh, I can't read the question tags to see the language, so I'm just going to assume it's my favourite. Oh, wait, it isn't? I guess you're all idiots then and I hope you enjoy your inferiority.". Not OK.

Comment: @DeadMG I'm really sorry if that's how you interpreted it. I don't consider C++ to be inferior to Java at all. I used to code in it at the job before last and I have no complaints about it. Honestly, why it showed up was I have Java and Homework as highlighted tags. Seeing it highlight I thought it was Java. You read a lot into my comments that really wasn't there. I know it's very common to bash one language for another, but I'm not a big fan of it (except OpenEdge 4GL...) Sorry my poor attempt at humor about segfaults didn't amuse you, but you've really overreacted here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you know the last element in the list will always be sorted (since it bubbled up to the top) you can stop there.

```
for(int x = size; x >= 0; x--) {
    bool switched = false;
    for(int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        if(blah) {
            // swap code here
            switched = true;
        }

    }
    if(!switched) break; // not the biggest fan of this but it gets the job done
}
```

Comment: If you don't like the `break` you could do `i<x && !switched` in the conditional.

Comment: @Jon Having graded CS101 homework before, yes I agree. This would be what the professor is most likely looking for, especially a small snippet about how 'most recently highest element' is always sorted.

Comment: @Jon That's true. I like `break` much more than that. Doing that puts the variable outside of the loop and therefore in a scope larger than it needs to be. Functions tend to grow large enough as it is, we shouldn't give people more variables than they need.

Comment: I'm a fan of the `break`, too.

Comment: Realize that the `break` is completely optional if you don't mind best case == worst case. Also wouldn't `x > 1` work for the first loop?

Comment: @Mark Yes it is optional, but if we don't break then we might as well just remove the switched flag to begin with. And you're probably right. I'd have to think about it a little bit more. I've honestly already done more than I typically care to do for homework-stype questions, so how about we leave the proof of the proper value for the first for loop as an exercise to the reader? :-D

Answer (score 5):

A bit obligate, but hey, you asked for it:

```
for(bool switched=true; switched;)
{
    switched = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[i-1]) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i-1];
            a[i-1] = temp;
            switched = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Two for loops...

Comment: I don't want to upvote because... wow it's bad! At the same time, I don't want to downvote because it's 1) clever and 2) correct. Torn!

Comment: You should be reported for cruel treatment of a `for` statement!

Comment: @glowcoder: feel free to not vote. Comment much appreciated! I was torn between this snappy answer and a jabby comment :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the maximum number of times your inner loop will run is `size` times, you know that the outer loop only can be bound by `size`.

```
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++ )
{
    switched = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[i - 1])
        {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i - 1];
            a[i - 1] = temp;
            switched = true;
        }
    }

    if(switched)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple improvement to bubble sort is to remember the **last** location where a swap occurred. After each pass the elements beyond that point are sorted. Next time through the loop only iterate up to the previous high water mark.

```
void bubble_sort(int *arr, int size)
{
    for (int hwm; size > 1; size = hwm)
    {
        hwm = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
        {
            if (arr[i] < arr[i-1])
            {
                std::swap(arr[i], arr[i-1]);
                hwm = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the inside loop `size` times instead of checking `switched`, by having an outer loop `for(int j=0; j<size; ++j)`. To make it slightly less badly inefficient you can make the inner loop 1 step shorter each time.

Answer (score 0):

The first full pass through the loop (that is, the first iteration of your outer `do` loop) is guaranteed to put the largest element in position `a[size - 1]`. (Do you see why?) The next full pass is guaranteed not to change that, *and*, in addition, to put the second-largest element in position `a[size - 2]`. (Again, do you see why?) And so on. So the first pass needs `i` to go from `1` to `size - 1`, but the second only needs `i` to go from `1` to `size - 2`, the third only needs `i` to go from `1` to `size - 3`, and so on. Overall, you need at most `size - 1` passes (with the last pass just covering position `1` and comparing `a[1]` to `a[0]` to make sure the smallest element is in place).

So, your outer `for`-loop needs to vary `max_i`, initially set to `size - 1` and ending up at `1`, and your inner `for`-loop needs to vary `i` from `1` to `max_i`.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the maximum number of times the `do` loop can execute.

Answer (score 0):

A really silly method to use two for loops would be as follows:

```
for(bool switched=true;switched;)
{
    switched=false;
    for(int i=1; i<size; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[i-1]) 
        {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i-1];
            a[i-1] = temp;
            switched = true;
        }
    }
}
```

A more serious answer might be as below... but now that I think about it this probably is not bubble sort:

```
for(int i=0; i<(size-1); ++i)
{
    for(int j=(i+1); j<(size-1); ++j)
    {
        if(a[i]>a[j])
        {
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```